# Django: how to retain context object passed to the render function for another render

Tags: django, django-views

I pass a context dictionary called `dict_context` in my render function and it renders using the data just fine.

```
return render(request, 'myapp/track.html', dict_context)
```

Now, in the rendered page, I have a button that will `POST` and I want to use the context dictionary again, but I receive this error:

```
UnboundLocalError at /track_containers_import_data
local variable 'dict_context' referenced before assignment
```

How can I reuse `dict_context` in the next render? I thought contexts are saved automatically in the sessions.

Answer (score 2):

The objects can be passed to other view functions or `POST` methods by storing in the session:

**storing objects in the current session inside the first view function:**

```
request.session['dict_context'] = dict_context
return render(request, 'myapp/track.html', dict_context)
```

**retrieve in any other view function in the same session:**

```
dict_context= request.session.get('dict_context', None) 
# ---------  do whatever you want with the object --------
return render(request, 'myapp/mytemplate.html', dict_context)
```